# Why is my Django Rest Framework Search filter not working?

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

Here is my code.  I get no errors, and I can see the search button that was added to the browsable API.  The problem though is the search does not work.  No matter what I type into the search, it just returns every objects.

```
from rest_framework import status, filters

class JobView(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.manager.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        if queryset.exists():
            serializer = JobSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response({"Returned empty queryset"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

endpoint

```
http://localhost:8000/jobs/?search=something
returns the same as
http://localhost:8000/jobs/
```

No matter what I put in the search string, it returns jobs.

Answer (score 7):

This basically doesn't work because you're trying to do too much.  You've written your own `get` method which bypasses all the magic of the DRF views.  In particular, by not calling `GenericAPIView.get_object`, you avoid a line that looks like

```
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
```

which is where the QuerySet is filtered.  This simpler version, practically identical to the one in [the SearchFilter docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter), should work

```
from rest_framework import status, filters, generics

class JobView(generics.LisaAPIView):
    queryset = Job.manager.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name']
```

NOTE based on your question, I am assuming:

1. that your `Job` model has a `name` field
2. that for some reason you've renamed the `Job` manager to `manager` via a call to `models.Manager()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should filter your queryset based on the parameter you're sending via GET, because it wont happen automatically. use `request.query_params.get('search')` to access your parameter.